# Make sure all string properties has length and unicode setting in EF 6.2

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

There is a big application with multiple `DbContext`s. There are many entities, across several projects, and each table has many string properties. Unfortunately, the string properties has no length or unicode setting defined, causing SQL Server to do an implicit parameter conversion that hurts performance.

I need a way to find all those properties without complete mapping, and if possible, enforce that they always have such settings.

I was thinking in retrieving the model metadata, and go through all mapped entities to check if there is a max length and a unicode setting for all the ones that are string. I would run this on the `OnModelCreating` override only when `if(DEBUG)`.

Which would be the best way of accomplish this? How to get all sets for a context, and iterate its properties metadata?